# Standalone 32-bit Assembly programs

Tags: libraries, 32-bit, fasm

I am a newbie in assembly and still trying to gain some basic foundation on assembly programming. I was a bit shocked when I discovered the fact that 32-bit protected mode assembly relies too much on the platform's libraries like c runtime library and Windows dlls just to print a simple string. e.g, the _printf call.

Is it possible for a 32-bit protected mode assembly to accomplish some serious routines without relying on the platform's libraries? Will the OS allow for such 'standalone' 32-bit programs to operate in their protected mode but without using any of the OS's services?

Is my question the correct question to ask? :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Interrupts on a Intel machine. But it is way too complex to create a call for every character/string to print.  Curious - Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Just curiousity I guess. I was doing fine in 16-bit but when I got into 32-bit, the dependency on platform's libraries is too much. Btw, I am a bit purist. I thought by learning assembly, we could get things done on our own without relying on the platform's library. Thanks for the reply